# Minimum volume size in GlusterFS/Heketi

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, nfs, glusterfs

I recently followed the official guide to setup [Heketi](https://github.com/heketi/heketi/blob/master/doc/admin/install-kubernetes.md) on Kubernetes. Everything works fine, except that whenever I create a drive smaller than 2GB it automatically creates a 2GB PV. I couldn't find any docs regarding t his behavior. Can anyone please me understand this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

The minimum volume size created by Heketi is 1GB.

The units followed in heketi(currently) is in terms of GBs and hence for example, when you create volume of size 1.8GB it creates 2GB volume.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/heketi/heketi/blob/master/docs/api/api.md#create-a-volume
Create a Volume

```
Method: POST
Endpoint:/volumes
Content-Type: application/json
Response HTTP Status Code: 202, See Asynchronous Operations
Temporary Resource Response HTTP Status Code: 303, Location header will contain /volumes/{id}. See Volume Info for JSON response.
JSON Request:
    **size: int, Size of volume requested in GiB**
```